# Date Sequence using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

SITUATION

I have a sequence of date serial numbers, for example:

```
42519, 42526, 42533, 42540, 42547, 42554
```

in cells

```
B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2
```

respectively.

Eventually there will be 52 date serial numbers, each one representing a Weekly Invoice Date.

You will notice that each one has been incremented by 7 in a previous macro, which presented no problems.

OBJECTIVE

I need to convert these  date serial numbers into a format `"dd-mmm-yy"`, using VBA mentioned in **Method 2** below (as opposed to copying formulas manually).

So let's say the first date number is `42519` in cell `B2`.

**Method 1.**

This method which converts Date Serial Number `42519` to `"dd-mmm-yy"` format  presents no problem to me but is long winded and involves formula copying manually:

Using  expression:

```
 Range("B3")="=TEXT(B2,""dd-mmm-yy"")"    ' returns 29-May-16 in cell B3
```

I can even use the expression:

```
 Range("C3")="=TEXT(B2+7,""dd-mmm-yy"")"    'returns 05-Jun-16 in cell C3
```

**Method 2.**

This has me stumped and I'm coming up against a brick wall. It was my idea to do something like the following and if I can get this to work I can go ahead and use a loop to generate 52 dates in a row of 52 cells (`C3`, `D3`, etc in the format `"dd-mmm-yy"`, each one incremented by 7 days over the period of a year):

```
Sub sbNumToText_01()
    Dim intAdd7 As Integer
    intAdd7 = 0
    Dim lngSerialDate As Long
    lngSerialDate = Range("C2").Value
    MsgBox lngSerialDate + intAdd7  'returns 42526, as expected
    Range("C3") = "=TEXT(lngSerialDate + intAdd7,""dd-mmm-yy"")"
End Sub
```

Instead of cell `C3` displaying `"05-Jun-16"`, cell `C3` displays `#Name?` and the mini drop down error menu on the left of cell `C3` says `"The formula contains unrecognised text"`.

Can any of you out there please explain how to use the `TEXT` function  incorporating variables? Or any other solution along these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the line

```
Range("C3") = "=TEXT(lngSerialDate + intAdd7,""dd-mmm-yy"")"
```

If you look at the formula in cell `C3` after running the macro, you'll see it contains

```
=TEXT(lngSerialDate + intAdd7,"dd-mmm-yy")
```

But `lngSerialDate` and `intAdd7` are VBA variables, not Excel names, so they are meaningless in a worksheet formula and that's why you see the error. What you want to do is convert the sum of those variables to a number *before* placing it in the worksheet function:

```
Range("C3") = "=TEXT(" & lngSerialDate + intAdd7 & ",""dd-mmm-yy"")"
```

Comment: Thank you, Nekomatic- it works well. I will 'play around' with it (being self-taught) until I understand the solution fully.

Comment: I'm getting a little academic here so please bear with me:- In my quest to understand the VBA language(of which I'm happy with my progress so far), I'm led to understand that the ampersand character has the same function as CONCATENATE. One of my attempts is :-

Comment: I'm getting a little academic here so please bear with me.  Could you please show me how to use the CONCATENATE formula in place of the ampersand in the line of code Range("C3") = "=TEXT(" & lngSerialDate + intAdd7 & ",""dd-mmm-yy"")". I'm getting a compile error of 'Expected:end of statement' when I tried Range("C3")="=TEXT(CONCATENATE("lngSerialDate+intAdd7,")""dd-mmm-yy"")"